# How to integrate monaco-editor into Angular app properly?

Tags: monaco-editor

There are two common ways for monaco-editor integration:

1. Integrate the [AMD version](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/blob/main/docs/integrate-amd.md)
2. Integrate the [ESM version](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/blob/main/docs/integrate-esm.md)

Since that angular-cli uses webpack under the hood seems that i should use ESM integration, but all plugins (angular wrappers for monaco) that i found use AMD intergration. At the same time i couldn't integrate ESM bundles due the runtime errors. I'm so confused. Which one way should I use for app with angular-cli app (ng v13)? And what's the main difference between two approaches? Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to use the ESM version with Angular 15 following these steps:

Note: I use nx, but it should work with other executers like [Angular builder](https://angular-builders.dev/home)
Note: I implemented this today and posted the answer right after so beer in mind that there might cases I haven't covered.

1. install monaco-editor-webpack-plugin
2. change the build target to use an executer that supports modifying the webpack config. in case of nx 16, use "@nx/angular:webpack-browser"
3. add webpack.config.js

angular.json/project.json

```json
{
  "build": {
    "executor": "@nx/angular:webpack-browser",
    "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
    "options": {
      "customWebpackConfig": {
        "path": "path/to/webpack.config.js"
      },
      ...rest of the options
   }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require('path');
const MONACO_DIR = path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'node_modules/monaco-editor');
const MonacoWebpackPlugin = require('monaco-editor-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [new MonacoWebpackPlugin()],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ttf$/,
        include: MONACO_DIR,
        use: ['file-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: MONACO_DIR,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

now, you might create a directive to instantiate the editor

```js
@Directive({
  standalone: true,
  selector: '[codeEditor]',
})
export class EditorDirective {
  editor?: editor.IStandaloneCodeEditor;
  hostEl = inject(ElementRef).nativeElement;
  constructor() {
    import('monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api').then(({ editor }) => {
      this.editor = editor.create(this.hostEl, {
        value: 'function hello() {\n\tconsole.log("Hello, world!");\n}',
        language: 'typescript',
        autoIndent: 'full',
        readOnly: true,
        domReadOnly: true,
      });
    });
  }
}
```

```
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  template: `<div codeEditor style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>`,
  styles: [`:host{display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%}`]
  imports: [EditorDirective],
})
export class YourComponent {}
```

Comment: Is the same thing possible with nx module federation? should anything be different?

Comment: @Dale I'm in the same boat and having tons of trouble on-and-off. Feel free to reach out to me (same username on X) and we can try to figure it out...

Comment: sorry folks, I never tried module federation before

Comment: Is this approach still working with recent versions of Nx and Angular?

Answer (score 0):

Done with AMD, but still stuck and confused with ESM. Have created repo for explanation: https://github.com/alxpsr/ng-monaco-editor-integration

Answer (score 0):

I've been maintaining the AMD-based wrapper for the Angular for a while: https://github.com/ngstack/code-editor. You can check the source code, or use the component if you find it useful.

Regarding ESM, integration into the app is still a complicated process. You can see a lot of examples for Monaco here: https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/tree/main/samples. The caveat is that you need to modify the default Angular configuration, and mess with the webpack settings (assuming you are using webpack and not some other bundler). If you want going that way, this article might be of help: https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/blob/main/docs/integrate-esm.md.

If you are a library author, and you choose the custom webpack configuration path, keep in mind that not all your users will want to tamper with the Angular CLI configs to make your component running. Even Monaco playground is based on AMD loader and React components, if you check their source code: https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/blob/main/website/src/monaco-loader.ts